# Regarding Ruby assert_equal

Tags: ruby, testunit

So I am learning Ruby through ruby koans tutorial.
In the about_assert.rb script, there is a comment regarding assert_equal,
**"Some ways of asserting equality are better than others"**

here is the code

```
def test_a_better_way_of_asserting_equality
    expected_value = 2
    actual_value = 1 + 1

    assert_equal expected_value, actual_value
end
```

my question is , why 
 **`assert_equal expected_value, actual_value`** is better than 
 **`assert expected_value == actual_value`**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I myself use Rspec, so I don't know for sure.

But I'd guess that the difference is with the message you get when assertion fails. 
In `assert_equal` you should get something like "Expected value to be X, got Y".
And in the other case you'll get just something like "Assertion failed".

You can do a quick test and verify or disprove my point :-)

Comment: If my memory is correct the error message is the (always helpful) expected true to be false

Answer (score 3):

Because assert_equal provides a better explanation message by default.

Here's the code from Ruby 1.9.3 minitest/unit.rb so you can see it's using == too:

```
def assert_equal exp, act, msg = nil
  msg = message(msg, "") { diff exp, act }
  assert(exp == act, msg)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the error message reasons stated already. `assert_equal` is self explanatory, `assert foo == bar` requires more cognitive overhead.